# code behind from adding AJAX exentenders, need explaination please

Tags: vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am working on adding some ajax controls for either a hover menu or popup control. But when I do I get the following code....

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute()>    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()> _ 
Public Shared Function GetDynamicContent(ByVal contextKey As System.String) As System.String 

End Function
```

I am trying to find out exactly how to code against this function. I am at a bit of a loss with regard to the WebMethodAttribute, and ScriptMethodAttribute, one would think I could delete one or the other.

I watched numerous videos by MS and others and this code behind is not covered.

If someone could point to some tutorials, MSDN, white papers, or web sites where this is used, or in a project or something, it would probably be a great help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebMethod` attribute marks the method as being part of a web service, which makes it callable by other code. `ScriptMethod` tells the compiler that this method will be called by client script e.g. JavaScript - the J in AJAX. And yes, you do have to have both attributes on a method to make it callable by AJAX - see the Remarks section of the [ScriptMethod reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx) on MSDN.

There's a [great piece](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113123/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071107-1.aspx) on 4GuysFromRolla on using the GetDynamicContent method in a GridView to build up some markup and return it to the browser.